# Codeigniter joining tables?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have this structure of the tables:

```
Table Name: collisions
Fields: id, creator1, creator2
(1, 1, 2) - simple data in my sql table

Table Name: creators
Fields: id, artistname
(1, john smith)- simple data in my sql table
(2, steven michael)- simple data in my sql table
```

What i need is to join these tables so i can get the artist name instead of creator1 id and creator 2 id.

This is what I have done so far:

```
$this->db->select('collisions.*, creators.artist_name AS cr1, creators.artist_name as cr2');
$this->db->join('creators', 'collisions.creator1 = cr1.id AND collisions.creator2 = cr2.id', 'left');
$data = $this->db->get('collisions')->result();
```

but I am getting this error:

```
Unknown column 'cr1.id' in 'on clause'

SELECT `collisions`.*, `creators`.`artist_name` AS cr1, `creators`.`artist_name` as cr2 FROM (`collisions`) LEFT JOIN `creators` ON `collisions`.`creator1` = `cr1`.`id` AND collisions.creator2 = cr2.id
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Avoid using alises they are creating problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the job

```
    $this->db->select('collisions.*, cr1.artist_name as cr1, cr2.artist_name as cr2');
    $this->db->join('creators AS cr1', 'collisions.creator1 = cr1.id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('creators AS cr2', 'collisions.creator2 = cr2.id', 'left');
    $data = $this->db->get('collisions')->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use actual table name instead of alias :

```
$this->db->select('collisions.*, creators.artist_name AS cr1, creators.artist_name as cr2');
$this->db->join('creators', 'collisions.creator1 = creators.id AND collisions.creator2 = creators.id', 'left');
$data = $this->db->get('collisions')->result();
```

the reason why you cant use alias is that the execution of sql is in the following order:

```
1)FROM clause
2)WHERE clause
3)GROUP BY clause
4)HAVING clause
5)SELECT clause
6)ORDER BY clause
```

since you were using alias which is created in **select** clause which executes after **where** clause.

That's why you can not use the alias that which does not exits.

Comment: this fixed the error, but i still dont get data on cr1 and cr2.